# Disable Auto switch of bluetooth device profiles (specifically input), when apps request it, in pipewire and ubuntu 23.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire, wireplumber

I faced the same issue as described in this [r/linuxquestions reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/lqtemw/prevent_microsoft_teams_from_changing_bluetooth/gojd730/) , but for pipewire instead.

In a nutshell: By default, the audio controllers and system allow apps to switch from high quality A2DP to HSP/HFP profiles, which happens because apps force you to use the mic of the bluetooth headset, which requires the low quality HSP profile, as far as I am aware. This happens for example in MS Teams, GMeet, and others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Automatic_profile_selection

One needs to create a global configuration file for wireplumber: `/etc/wireplumber/policy.lua.d/11-bluetooth-policy.lua` (or a user-specific one at `~/.config/wireplumber/`)

and add the following option:

```
bluetooth_policy.policy["media-role.use-headset-profile"] = false
```

Restart pipewire or your machine and now the profiles shouldn't change automatically, and thus preserve manual control of input / mic settings across apps!